# DbContextTransaction clarification about Rollback

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This code:

```
using(var context = this.contextFactory.Create()) // creates a context
using(var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) // starts a transaction
{
    try
    {
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Save my changes

        transaction.Commit(); // Commit my changes
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        transaction.RollBack(); // Rollback my changes
    }
}
```

Am I correct in saying that if the `transaction.Commit()` throws and error, then the `transaction` will be rolled back?

Not just in the scenario of creating and entity or adding an entity to a `DbSet<>`. I assume I am correct, but just want to make sure.

Comment: Not sure how `Commit` could throw an error (other than no transaction being valid to commit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A transaction either commits or rolls back. There is no in-between.

If `Commit` throws it depends on the specific error what you can conclude from it. Network and timeout errors do not allow you to tell whether the transaction was committed in the store or not.

You do not need to explicitly rollback. As I said, there is no in-between. If the transaction does not commit it is certain to roll back. I don't know why so many people on the web decide to roll back explicitly. Probably, you just saw wrong sample code. The standard pattern is to do nothing in case of an error.

The error bubbles up, causes rollback and is eventually handled in a place where something can be done about it.

You are swallowing the exception. Very dangerous.

Comment: I don't just swallow the exception in my application, it propagates out (re thrown) to be handled later. The sample code was off of MSDN. I can remove `RollBack`, it was probably in there for clarity!

Comment: It is not surprising at all to hear this. I think many of the MSDN samples are so embarrassingly wrong that they proliferate bad practices.